# Log4Net does not send email in Windows Service module

Tags: email, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I'm using Log4Net in an assembly. When using that assembly in unit test module, the Log4Net sends email in specified case, but when running my windows service, it doesn't send email in the same case. App.Config is the same for both windows service and unit test module. I'm using "Network Service" credential for the windows service. platform is windows Server 2008 R2

Any help is welcome
Thank you.

Comment: Make sure your SMTP server is configured to allow anonymous users to send mail.

Comment: Thanks for response but i believe it's not the problem as it works from my local PC.